# Android Studio don't run app after upgrade to 1.5

Tags: android-studio

I just upgraded Android Studio to 1.5 release and I try (after gradle build)  to run App but the run procedure is skipped and the device chooser immediately appears. No apk file issued. Any suggestion? Is a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio15preview2available

> We've just released Android Studio 1.5 Preview 2 to the Canary
>   channel.
>
> In 1.5 we've reworked the build+deploy flow such that instead of first
>   building with Gradle and then popping up the "choose a device" dialog,
>   we now immediately ask for a device to push the APK to. Some users
>   were using Run + Cancel to build an APK; we now added a separate
>   "Build APK" action to the Build menu for that purpose.

Hi. It is not a bug, it is a feature. Personaly I hate this change and hope I can enable this optionaly.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Anyway the "Build APK" action is very welcome.